# TouchableRipple onPress is not working with react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, touchableopacity, react-native-paper

I am using stack navigator in my app to navigate through different components. but here I am facing 2 different issues. issue (1) I used a switch to toggle between dark and light theme, in the module, it works fine when using onPress but when called through stack screen it is not working. issue (2) I wanted to give some space between header text and the switch button but every time I add some padding to switch component, it is also applied to the header text. How can I solve these issues?
Here is App.js Component code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {StatusBar, View} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import Home from './src/screens/Home';
import Details from './src/screens/Details';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {DarkTheme, Text, Title} from 'react-native-paper';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();


const App = () => {


  const Darkthemebtntoggle = () => {
    return (
        <Details />
      
    );
  };

  return (
    <>
   
      <NavigationContainer>
        <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign: ''}}>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{
              headerTitle: (props) => (
                  <Darkthemebtntoggle {...props} />
              ),
            }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </> 
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here is also Details.js component code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {TouchableRipple, Switch, Title} from 'react-native-paper';

function Details() {
  const [isDartheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false);

  const togglemethod = () => {
    setDarkTheme(!isDartheme);
  };
  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
        <View >
             <Title>
            <Text >Home</Text>
          </Title>
        </View>
     
      <View style={{ paddingLeft:10, flexDirection:"row"}}>
        <TouchableRipple
          onPress={() => {
            togglemethod();
          }}>
          <View pointerEvents="none">
            <Switch value={isDartheme} />
          </View>
        </TouchableRipple>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default Details;
```

Here is a screenshot of the behavior of the header:

[image]

Comment: did you solve this ? I am facing the same problem

Comment: the solution I used is removing the TouchableRipple and just use only the switch and use onValueChange={toggleTheme}, thats will work